# regex to extract numbers from string

Tags: regex

I have multiple strings and I want to extract only matching numbers .

Sample strings :

```
abc_efghi_92458_ijk_mno_uvw_test_v2_ghi003
AB_CD_E01_436873_MY_NAME_TESTING_O_001
testing-check-100001-23244-sln-001
```

I am expecting output as :

```
92458
436873
23244
```

I tried with `+([^_]+)` and `+([\d{5,6}]+)`

No luck
Thanks

Comment: Please edit your sample strings because we don't know your strings are in 1 single line or multi-line.

Comment: Does it have to be using regex? You can just simply iterate through each character, and if it is a number then add it to the result string or list.

Answer (score 1):

For your example data you might use a capturing group and a backreference.

The value is in group 2

```
.*([-_])(\d+)\1
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CJQJ3R/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply iterable throw each string from the list.
Then apply this regex: `.*([-_])(\d+)\1` and get the group 2 if it matches. Then add the output to the result.

Comment: That pattern looks familiar :)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you any contiguous sequence of numbers:

```
/[.*!\d](\d+)[.*!\d]/g
```

```js
let arr = [
    "abc_efghi_92458_ijk_mno_uvw_test_v2_ghi003",
    "AB_CD_E01_436873_MY_NAME_TESTING_O_001",
    "testing-check-100001-23244-sln-001"
]

let re = /[.*!\d](\d+)[.*!\d]/g

let res = arr.map(str => str.match(re))

console.log(res)
```